# Как вернуть значение в двусвязном списке?

Tags: c++, list, двусвязный-список

Вставляю кусок кода. нужно вывести  ((p1->info + p2->info) / 2) в srzn. насчёт идеи кода на самом деле вообще не уверена, но мне хотя бы с этим разобраться сначала.

```
//Дан список из n целых чисел 
// 
// Выдать на экран те из них, которые меньше среднего арифметического своих двух соседей(для крайних элементов
//      отсутствующего соседа считать равным нулю).

//среднее значение следующего и предыдущего элементов
ListElement* srzn(ListElement* p)
{

    ListElement* p1 = p->pred;
    ListElement* p2 = p->next;
    ListElement* p3 = ((p1->info + p2->info) / 2);
    return p3;
}

void sravn(ListElement* head, ListElement* tail)
{

    ListElement* p = head->next;
    ListElement* arr = srzn(p);
    while (p != tail)
    {
        if (p->info < arr->info)
        {
            cout << p << endl;
        }
        else
            p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, прямо в условии говорится, что элементов по соседству может и не быть.
Во-вторых, вы должны возвращать *значение*, а не указатель на элемент (которого нет).

Вы дали фрагмент, без описания, что у вас и как, потому возвращаю не более чем набросок:

```
int sum(ListElement* p)
{

    int p1 = p->pred ? p->pred->info : 0;
    int p2 = p->next ? p->next->info : 0;
    return p1 + p2;
}

void sravn(ListElement* head, ListElement* tail)
{

    for(ListElement* p = head->next; p != tail; p=p->next)
        if (p->info*2 < sum(p))
        {
            cout << p << endl;
        }
}
```

Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что в последней функции идете не до конца списка, а до элемента `tail`, исключая его? Чтобы дойти до конца, `tail` должен быть нулевым указателем.

Comment: выводится на экран то же что и вводилось. я так понимаю это из-за того что не учитывается отсутствие элементов соседних?

Comment: Не понял ваш вопрос. Как не учитывается? Что вы вводите? Правильно ли? я же не вижу ни код, ни ввод...